# Get variable of a class out of the scope with coffeescript

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I have that code :

```
class @Validator


  ##
  # Constructor
  #
  # Set basic variables
  #
  ##
  constructor: ->

    @_errors = {}

  ##
  # Errors
  ##
  errors:

    first: ->

    last: ->

    all: =>

      return @_errors 

    get: ->
```

In the method `all()` of the object `errors` it's impossible to reach the content of the variable `_errors`, how it's possible to reach it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the API you're after is this

```
validator = new Validator()
validator.errors.all()
```

then place the errors object within the constructor and also change

```
errors:
    first: ->
```

to

```
errors =
    first: ->
```

Otherwise, just change

```
errors:
    first: ->
```

to

```
errors: ->
    first: ->
```

making the API look like this `validator.errors().all()`